# Splitting string into words length-based lists c#

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a string of words separated by spaces. How to split the string into lists of words based on the words length?

**Example**

> input:
>
> ```
> " aa aaa aaaa bb bbb bbbb cc ccc cccc cccc bbb bb aa "
> ```
>
> output :
>
> ```
> List 1 = { aa, bb, cc}
> List 2 = { aaa, bbb, ccc}
> List 3 = { aaaa, bbbb, cccc}
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Edit:** I'm glad my original answer helped the OP solve their problem. However, after pondering the problem a bit, I've adapted it (and I strongly advise *against* my former solution, which I have left at the end of the post).

## A simple approach

```
string input = " aa aaa aaaa bb bbb bbbb cc ccc cccc cccc bbb bb aa ";
var words = input.Trim().Split().Distinct();
var lookup = words.ToLookup(word => word.Length);
```

### Explanation

First, we trim the input to avoid empty elements from the outer spaces. Then, we split the string into an array. If multiple spaces occur *in between the words*, you'd need to use `StringSplitOptions` as as in [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11378353/1106367).

After calling `Distinct` to only include each word once, we now convert `words` from  `IEnumerable<string>` to `Lookup<int, string>`, where the words' length is represented by the  key `(int)` and the words themselves are stored in the value `(string)`.

Hang on, how is that even possible? Don't we have multiple words for each key? Sure, but that's exactly what the [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184) class is there for:

> **`Lookup<TKey, TElement>`** represents a collection of keys each mapped to one or more 
>   values.
>   A `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` resembles a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. The difference is that 
>   a Dictionary maps keys to single values, whereas a Lookup 
>   maps keys to *collections of values*.
>
> You can create an instance of a `Lookup` by calling `ToLookup` on an object
>   that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.
>
> ---
>
> **Note**
>   There is no public constructor to create a new instance of a Lookup. 
>   Additionally, Lookup objects are immutable, that is, you cannot add or 
>   remove elements or keys from a Lookup after it has been created.

`word => word.Length` is the *KeySelector* lambda: it defines that we want to index (or group, if you will) the `Lookup` by the Length of the words.

### Usage

#### Write all the words to the console

*(similar to the question's originally requested output)*

```
foreach (var grouping in lookup)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", grouping.Key, string.Join(", ", grouping));
}
```

**Output**

> ```
> 2: aa, bb, cc
> 3: aaa, bbb, ccc
> 4: aaaa, bbbb, cccc
> ```

#### Put all words of a certain length in a `List`

```
List<String> list3 = lookup[3].ToList();
```

#### Order by key

*(note that these will return `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, so access by key is no longer possible)*

```
var orderedAscending = lookup.OrderBy(grouping => grouping.Key);
var orderedDescending = lookup.OrderByDescending(grouping => grouping.Key);
```

---

Original answer - please *don't do this* (bad performance, code clutter):

```
string input = " aa aaa aaaa bb bbb bbbb cc ccc cccc cccc bbb bb aa ";
Dictionary<int, string[]> results = new Dictionary<int, string[]>();
var grouped = input.Trim().Split().Distinct().GroupBy(s => s.Length)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key); // or: OrderByDescending(g => g.Key);
foreach (var grouping in grouped)
{
    results.Add(grouping.Key, grouping.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I think we need to group the words by counts first, so that we reduce the number or words. then we could separate them into lists of arrays based on their lengths. I'm I right ?

Comment: @Qaesar `words.Distinct().GroupBy(s => s.Length);` is working for me. Isn't it giving you the expected result?

Comment: Can I do it without using string[] words = input.Split(); ?? I mean directly spiting the string ?

Comment: Great, but why the words of each length are separated by comma. I would like to each word be an element of array or list. So we can use array of array or list of list. does this better?

Comment: @Qaesar sure ;) take a look at my edited answer. If this isn't sufficient, it might be a sign you need to edit your question and be a lot more specific about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `Where` to find elements that match a predicate (in this case, having the correct length):

```
string[] words = input.Split();

List<string> twos = words.Where(s => s.Length == 2).ToList();
List<string> threes = words.Where(s => s.Length == 3).ToList();
List<string> fours = words.Where(s => s.Length == 4).ToList();
```

Alternatively you could use `GroupBy` to find all the groups at once:

```
var groups = words.GroupBy(s => s.Length);
```

You can also use `ToLookup` so that you can easily index to find all the words of a specific length:

```
var lookup = words.ToLookup(s => s.Length);
foreach (var word in lookup[3])
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Result:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/nlyzc)

---

In your update it looks like you want to remove the empty strings and duplicated words. You can do the former by using `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` and the latter by using `Distinct`.

```
var words = input.Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .Distinct();
var lookup = words.ToLookup(s => s.Length);
```

Output:

```
aa, bb, cc
aaa, bbb, ccc
aaaa, bbbb, cccc
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/HyDAE)

Comment: The first variant will iterate `words` three times.  For a small `input` that probably will not matter.

Comment: @Mark do you know if there is anything similar to ideone *with* code completion? or does ideone support it and I just didn't find it?

Answer (score 3):

First, let's declare a class that can hold a length as well as a list of words

```
public class WordList
{
    public int WordLength { get; set; }
    public List<string> Words { get; set; }
}
```

Now, we can build a list of word lists with

```
string input = " aa aaa aaaa bb bbb bbbb cc ccc cccc ";
string[] words = input.Trim().Split();
List<WordList> list = words
    .GroupBy(w => w.Length)
    .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
    .Select(group => new WordList { 
        WordLength = group.Key, 
        Words = group.Distinct().OrderBy(s => s).ToList() 
    })
    .ToList();
```

The lists are sorted by length and aphabetically respectively.

---

Result

[image]

e.g.

```
list[2].WordLength ==> 4
list[2].Words[1] ==> "bbbb"
```

---

#### UPDATE

If you want, you can process the result immediately, instead of putting it into a data structure

```
string input = " aa aaa aaaa bb bbb bbbb cc ccc cccc ";

var query = input
    .Trim()
    .Split()
    .GroupBy(w => w.Length)
    .OrderBy(group => group.Key);

// Process the result here
foreach (var group in query) {
    // group.Key ==> length of words
    foreach (string word in group.Distinct().OrderBy(w => w)) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I inserted a screenshot of the debugger Locals window.

Comment: Can I do it without the string []? I mean input.split directly.

Comment: Yes, replace `words.GroupBy(...` by `input.Trim().Split().GroupBy(...`.

Comment: @ Olivier, is there any suggestion for suitable data structure of the outputs instead of using list ? because after that, i will write each list into excel column. thank you

Comment: I updated my answer to show a simple approach, if you don't need to store the result in some kind of data structure. Note: The LINQ queries do not store the result, instead they generate the result as it is being looped through on the fly. In fact the query is not even executed in `var query = input ...`.

Comment: @ Olivier, the list or words contains a repeated word, but i want to group them without repeat. Example, if "ccc" accrued 2 times, i want one "ccc" in the list.

Comment: +1 for the nice answer and your "StackOverflowTests" namespace. Mine is called "StackOverflowPlayground" :)

Comment: @Qaesar: Shure, I added a `.Distinct()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq GroupBy

**edit**
Now I applied Linq to generate the string list you wanted for output.

**edit2**
applied multiple input, single output as in edited question. It is just a Distinct call in Linq

```
string input = " aa aaa aaaa bb bbb bbbb cc ccc cccc ";

var list = input.Split(' ');

var grouped = list.GroupBy(s => s.Length);

foreach (var elem in grouped)
{
    string header = "List " + elem.Key + ": ";
    // var line = elem.Aggregate((workingSentence, next) => next + ", " + workingSentence);

    // if you want single items, use this
    var line = elem.Distinct().Aggregate((workingSentence, next) => next + ", " + workingSentence);
    string full = header + " " + line;
    Console.WriteLine(full);
}


// output: please note the last blank in the input string! this generates the 0 list
List 0:  ,
List 2:  cc, bb, aa
List 3:  ccc, bbb, aaa
List 4:  cccc, bbbb, aaaa
```

Comment: @ Mare, does your code will list the words or just the lengths ? please, is it match the output of the original post?

Comment: in this example it will output the length and then the words, each of those in one line.

Comment: @ Mare, GREAT .... but I want to put the words of each length in a list or is there any suggestion for suitable data structure of the outputs? is it good to use a Jagged Array ?

Comment: have edited the example to match your needs. If you give me an example of your jagged array, I will build you a Linq suiting to that. Note: Linq delivers a GroupedEnumerable from the GroupBy. this contains a key, which is in this case the length, and the elements in the group.

Comment: @ Mare, is there any suggestion for suitable data structure of the outputs instead of using list ? because after that, i will write each list into excel column. thank you

Comment: GroupBy delivers a GroupedEnumerable, which can easily be transformed to anything that you need or is more suitable for you. What do you want? With aggregate I generate a comma separated list now, this will easily fit in excel, but we can tab separate it to, so you can copy and paste it into excel even more easily.

Comment: two points. Minor problem: In the question, sequential numbering was requested, your answer outputs `Grouping.Key` instead. Major problem (IMHO): the call to `Aggregate` is confusing and overkill when [a simple `string.Join` would suffice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11378664/1106367)...

Comment: First: The key is a number here, it is the length. Second: a simple string.Join will not suffice, you have a GroupedEnumberable and you will need some Linq in any way, ToArray and join or only Linq, which is Aggregate here. To me Aggregate is the more direct and clear way, as it expresses what is done directly

Comment: Works as good as the previous in my testing application. Should the output be sorted or something like that?

Comment: he wants the output to stay the same (unique). The output of your code will produce multiple `bb` entries, for instance. @Qaesar have you taken a look at my solution?

Comment: Does he want? Thats not that much of a problem for Linq, just another call to achieve that.

Comment: @Qaesar: if you want the single items in your list, try `var line = elem.Distinct().Aggregate((workingSentence, next) => next + ", " + workingSentence);` ... no duplicates in that.

Comment: Great, but why the words of each length are separated by comma. I would like to each word be an element of array or list. So we can use array of array or list of list. does this better?

Comment: It is already in an array. I just transformed it to meet the output you expected. You could simple use what is in the result of Distrinct() or call another ToArray(). But, I see, you accepted another answer after all.

Answer (score 0):

A bit lengthy solution but does get the result in a Dictionary

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Print();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Print()
        {
            GetListOfWordsByLength();

            foreach (var list in WordSortedDictionary)
            {
                list.Value.ForEach(i => { Console.Write(i + ","); });
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        private static void GetListOfWordsByLength()
        {
            string input = " aa aaa aaaa bb bbb bbbb cc ccc cccc ";

            string[] inputSplitted = input.Split(' ');

            inputSplitted.ToList().ForEach(AddToList);
        }

        static readonly SortedDictionary<int, List<string>> WordSortedDictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, List<string>>();

        private static void AddToList(string s)
        {
            if (s.Length > 0)
            {
                if (WordSortedDictionary.ContainsKey(s.Length))
                {
                    List<string> list = WordSortedDictionary[s.Length];
                    list.Add(s);
                }
                else
                {
                    WordSortedDictionary.Add(s.Length, new List<string> {s});
                }
            }
        }
    }
```