# Converting Lookup<TKey, TElement> into other data structures c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lookup

I have a

```
Lookup<TKey, TElement>
```

where the TElement refers to a string of words. I want to convert 
    Lookup  into:

```
Dictionary<int ,string []> or List<List<string>> ?
```

I have read some articles about using the

```
Lookup<TKey, TElement>
```

but it wasn't enough for me to understand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do that using these methods:

- [`Enumerable.ToDictionary<TSource, TKey>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx)
- [`Enumerable.ToList<TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)

Lets say you have a `Lookup<int, string>` called `mylookup` with the strings containing several words, then you can put the `IGrouping` values into a `string[]` and pack the whole thing into a dictionary:

```
var mydict = mylookup.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToArray());
```

**Update**

Having read your comment, I know what you actually want to do with your lookup (see the ops [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378338/spliting-string-into-words-length-based-lists-c-sharp)). You dont have to convert it into a dictionary or list. Just use the lookup directly:

```
var wordlist = " aa bb cc ccc ddd ddd aa ";
var lookup = wordlist.Trim().Split().Distinct().ToLookup(word => word.Length);

foreach (var grouping in lookup.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
{
    // grouping.Key contains the word length of the group
    Console.WriteLine("Words with length {0}:", grouping.Key);

    foreach (var word in grouping.OrderBy(x => x))
    {
        // do something with every word in the group
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }
}
```

Also, if the order is important, you can always sort the `IEnumerable`s via the `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` extension methods.

**Edit:**

look at the edited code sample above: If you want to order the keys, just use the `OrderBy` method. The same way you could order the words alphabetically by using `grouping.OrderBy(x => x)`.

Comment: @Qaesar: I guess your referring to your other question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378338/spliting-string-into-words-length-based-lists-c-sharp), right? There you have a ``Lookup<int, string>``. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: yes, exactly. I want to group a string of words according to the word lengths. so which structure is preferable ? can I keep using Lookup<TKey, TElement> ?? because after that i will write each TElement (array of words) into excel column.

Comment: Ok, but word must be splitting into array or something else. because later, i will write each (word in word) into a cell of excel column.

Comment: It is already splitted into words. Look at the ``foreach`` inside a ``foreach``.

Comment: I think you're a little bit confused what a ``Lookup`` exactly is. Imagine a list of groups; each group has a key and a list again. A ``Lookup<int, string>`` is similarly structured as a ``Dictionary<int, string[]>``.

Comment: @ Philip, But i want the keys are ordered.

Comment: @ Philip, can I return the lookup?. and assume I'm using the procedure " private Lookup<int ,string > wordgrouping(string input).

Comment: Not quite, the ``ToLoopup`` method returns some object with the ``ILookup`` interface. Your method would look like: ``private ILookup<int, string> WordGrouping(string input) { return input.Trim().Split().Distinct().ToLookup(word => word.Length); }``

Comment: i checked the code of your last comment, why the ILookup returns null strings ??

Comment: @Qaesar: what is the input string?

Comment: string of words separated and spaces. one thing more, the ILookup doesn't return the string. it returns the counts only (:

Comment: @Qaesar: No, it doesnt return counts only, but a list of groupings which in turn contain the counts and the lists of words, like I already explained. ``string.Split`` can never contain ``null`` values, so the error must be somewhere else. This goes much to far away from the original question. If you still have trouble, please ask a new stackoverflow question.

Comment: @Philip Daubmeier: +1 for your endless patience.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes: I'm here to help :)

Comment: @Qaesar: I must agree that the groups returned by `GroupBy` are a bit confusing. Intellisense shows only a `Key` property but no list of anything. However, you will also discover a `GetEnumerator()` method. This is a hint telling you that the group implements `IEnumerable<T>` and this again means that you can loop through the items contained in the group with `foreach` or apply another LINQ extension method to it.

Answer (score 5):

A lookup is a collection of mappings from a key to a collection of values. Given a key you can get the collection of associated values:

```
TKey key;
Lookup<TKey, TValue> lookup;
IEnumerable<TValue> values = lookup[key];
```

As it implements [`IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx)  you can use the enumerable extension methods to transform it to your desired structures:

```
Lookup<int, string> lookup = //whatever
Dictionary<int,string[]> dict = lookup.ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToArray());
List<List<string>> lists = lookup.Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! for "values = lookup[key]".  Everyone else is saying, "hey, you can foreach through the results," and I was ready to give up on being able to Linq the lookup results into an array.