# How to await on IObservable of IObservables?

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive

I have an `IObservable` of objects, which I want to convert to dictionary of lists asynchronously.

Here is my code, where GetSource returns an `IObservable`:

```
await GetSource(...)
  .GroupBy(o => o.SiteId)
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList())
```

Of course, it is wrong, because the result is `IDictionary<int, IObservable<IList<T>>>`, but I need an `IDictionary<int, IList<T>>`

In essence, I need to `await` each and every `IObservable<IList<T>>`, but I do not know how to do it as elegantly as I am convinced is possible with Rx.NET.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that whatever you do, you can never complete the dictionary until after the source has completed. A simple approach would therefore be to asynchronously obtain the list like this:

```
await GetSource(...).ToList();
```

and then proceed with the resulting `IList<T>` as you were with the `GroupBy` and `ToDictionary` - noting that you are now using the `IEnumerable<T>` implementations of these operators against a completed list.

This approach assumes that amount and timing of the events in the `GetSource()` observable, and the distribution between the groups is such that the expense of computing the groups and dictionaries on the completed stream is not prohibitive. Since ultimately you are returning a completed dictionary which will be held in memory anyway we are likely only considering the cost of sorting into groups and creating dictionary entries. This will be extremely fast on in memory data compared to the serialized delivery of a lengthy event stream, so I tend to think that there are few cases where this approach isn't perfectly fine.

If it is prohibitive, it may be worth building up each group and list concurrently and the events arrive, in which case you could do this instead:

```
await GetSource(...).GroupBy(x => x.SiteId)
                    .SelectMany(x => x.ToList())
                    .ToDictionary(x => x[0].SiteId);
```

Note that the first element of the list in the `ToDictionary` keySelector *will* always exist (otherwise no group would have been materialized), so this is safe. It does look a little odd, but it's the easiest way I can think of to get the key out.

Or as a general purpose function:

```
async Task<IDictionary<TKey, IList<T>>> ToDictionaryOfLists<T, TKey>(
    IObservable<T> source,
    Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
{        
    return await source.GroupBy(keySelector)
                       .SelectMany(x => x.ToList())
                       .ToDictionary(x => keySelector(x[0]));           
}
```

Which assuming a class:

```
public class Site
{
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
}
```

You could use like:

```
var result = ToDictionaryOfLists(GetSource(...), x=> x.SiteId);
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
I just learned that Task returning Select(...) + Merge() can be replaced by SelectMany(...) so better approach would be:

```
IDictionary<int, IList<Site>> result = await GetSource()
.GroupBy(o => o.SiteId)
.SelectMany(async group => (group.Key, List: await group.ToList()))
.ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.List);
```

Original:

I just started learning RX but maybe something like this is good enough:

```
IDictionary<int, IList<Site>> result = await GetSource()
.GroupBy(o => o.SiteId)
.Select(async group => (group.Key, List: await group.ToList()))
.Merge()
.ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.List);
```

Assuming Site implementation like:

```
public class Site
{
   public int SiteId { get; set; }
   //rest of class
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't actually need a `Dictionary` but a [`Lookup<TKey,TElement>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2).

> Represents a collection of keys each mapped to one or more values.

Creating a `Lookup` is trivial, by using the built-in RX operator `ToLookup`. [Converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383384/converting-lookuptkey-telement-into-other-data-structures-c-sharp) a `Lookup` to a `Dictionary` of lists is also trivial, by using the standard LINQ operator `ToDictionary`. Below are both of these operators combined in a single extension method:

```
public static async Task<Dictionary<TKey, List<TSource>>> ToDictionaryOfLists<TSource, TKey>(
    IObservable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var lookup = await source.ToLookup(keySelector);
    return lookup.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
}
```