# Remap Lookup keys in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures

I have my Lookup looking like this:

```
Lookup<string, DataModel> lookup;
```

Besides that I have dictionary containing key mappings:

```
Dictionary<string, KeyModel> keyMappings;
```

What I want to do is to re-map string keys in lookup to the `KeyModel` entities in the following way:

```
Lookup    <string, DataModel> lookup;
             ||
             ||
Dictionary<string, KeyModel> keyMappings;
            ___________|
           v
Lookup<KeyModel, DataModel> result;
```

Comment: So a string in your Dictionay matches a string in your Lookup ?

Comment: why not have a `Dictionary<string, [object containing DataModel and KeyModel]>`?

Comment: @Mauricio Gracia yes, exactly

Comment: @austin wernli because I expect it to be `Dictionary<KeyModel, IEnumerable<DataModel>>` but in the form of Lookup which i think is better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
Dictionary<string, KeyModel> keyMappings = ...;
ILookup<string, DataModel> lookup = ...;
```

the response is:

```
ILookup<KeyModel, DataModel> lookup2 = lookup
    .SelectMany(x => x, (grouping, element) => new { Key = keyMappings[grouping.Key], Element = element })
    .ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Element);
```

So you first re-linearize the `ILookup<,>` by using `SelectMany`, and then recreate the `ILookup<,>`.

Clearly you need your `KeyModel` to define the `GetHashCode()` and the `Equals()`, or you need an `IEqualityComparer<KeyModel>` to pass as the parameter of the `ToLookup()`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be efficient though, if I use `Dicitonary<KeyModel, IEnumerable<DataModel>>` (which basically represents the same thing) I  could remap it like `lookup.ToDictionary(k => keyMappings[k.Key], k => k.Select(data => data));` Does it look good?

Comment: @AndriyHoren There is a certain Andrij Horen that asked a very precise question, something with beautiful arrows that converged to a `Lookup<KeyModel, DataModel> result;`... You know him? :-)

Comment: @andriy But yes, if you are happy with a `Dictionary<KeyMode, IEnumerable<DataModel>>` then that line is ok. You don't even need the select, you could: `lookup.ToDictionary(k => keyMappings[k.Key], k => k.AsEnumerable());`. This will cut a middle-man (the `Select`) when you'll try to enumerate the values... Note that the `IGrouping` is array-backed, so there is no problem about enumerating multiple times the `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: Cool at least I wont need to create anonymous object for every element, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `foreach`-loop.

First you need to transform your Lookup into a Dictionary. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383384/converting-lookuptkey-telement-into-other-data-structures-c-sharp).

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DataModel> kvp in lookup) {
KeyModel outValue;
if (keyMappings.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out outValue))
{
    result.Add(outValue, lookup[kvp.Key]);
}}
```

Not the fastest solution, maybe someone is coming up with a nice LINQ.

Comment: I think you made the same mistake as I did at first. `lookup` is of type `Lookup` not `Dictionary` so each element is an `IGrouping` not `KeyValuePair`

Comment: I dont think that `Add` method is available for lookups, but i'll anyway convert to dictionary, thanks for help

Comment: @user2697817 Thats why i suggested to transform the existing Lookup<string, DataModel> lookup; into a Dictionary.

Comment: @AndriyHoren use a Dictionary as "result" and transform this later to Lookup via .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value); Edit: corrected typo